# Why does Visual Studio Code think "import pygame" is an error?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, import, pygame

So, I've recently installed [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/docs/) and every time I program with it in Visual Studio Code, the .py file runs fine. This is the thing, VSC underlines `import pygame` with yellow, stating it's an error. It's annoying to me because I can't autofill ANY of the pygame functions. When I click "View Problem", it says "Import "pygame" could not be resolved." Yes, I've tried using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have your `init` function:

```
pygame.init()
```

If you haven't initialized `pygame`, it's possible that VScode underlines it to warn you.

(Pylance)
You could also try to add `./sources` in the VScode settings:
[image]

(Pylint)
or go in your `.vscode` folder in `settings.json`. Under user settings paste this:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--extension-pkg-whitelist=pygame" 
]
```

Comment: I did "pygame.init()" already, it's still giving me that error. :/

Comment: Did you also try to add `./sources`?

Comment: idk how to get to that :(

Comment: Are you using pylint or pylance?

Comment: yes, im using pylance

Comment: `import pygame` would obviously have to come before `pygame.init()`, so I don't see how this could possibly solve an error with importing.

Comment: Ok, search up pylance in extensions, and then if you scroll down you should see a "Extra path setting". There,  paste in `./sources`.

Comment: okay I add ./sources and i went back to my code and "import pygame" is still underlined

Comment: You may have to restart vscode

Comment: theres still an error after restarting :<

Comment: pycharm seems to work so ¯\_(ツ)_/¯